# Yii add condition in 'visible' attribute in CMenu

Tags: yii

I want to make a condition in displaying a menu item in CMenu by limiting it only to one user ,for example, with the name of 'admin'. I am writing this

```
'items'=>array(
            array('label'=>'Logs','url'=>array('actionLogs/admin'),'icon'=>'wrench white',
            'visible'=>!Yii::app()->user->isGuest),
```

This condition works fine. Next I try to complicate a little the condition of the visibility, but it fails at all

```
'items'=>array(
                array('label'=>'Logs','url'=>array('actionLogs/admin'),'icon'=>'wrench white',
                'visible'=>'!Yii::app()->user->isGuest && Yii::app()->user->name=="admin"'),
```

How can I achieve what I am trying to do? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, found the solution. For those who will meet the same problem, here's the code:

```
'items'=>array(
                array('label'=>'Logs','url'=>array('actionLogs/admin'),'icon'=>'wrench white',
                'visible'=>(!Yii::app()->user->isGuest && Yii::app()->user->name=="admin")),
```

and force reload without caching.(Ctrl+F5)

Comment: how to check the visible with login session